# Akka Actors sequential ordering of messages

Tags: akka, actor, actor-model

I'm a little bit confused with Akka Actors and the Actor Model. Do the messages sent from Actor A to Actor B preserve the order? How can this be achieved in a local/network environment? As far as I know, the network introduces variable latency, how can a message M1 and a message M2 preserve the order if the latency of M1 is 1 second and M2 is 0.5 seconds?

Comment: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.14/general/message-delivery-reliability.html#Discussion__Message_Ordering

Comment: @ViktorKlang Is the re-implementation of the remote message transport (for maintaining message ordering like in a local environment) in progress?

Answer (score 0):

As the link Viktor Klang posts states: Basically you are guaranteed that messages between two specific actors will arrive in the order they are sent between the sender and receiver but that does not mean that if another actor sends to the receiver the order will be preserved in the receiver's queue from messages from a different sender. Aka if A1 and A3 are both sending to A2 then all messages from A1 will be in the queue in the order they were sent from A1. Same is true of messages from A3 but they may be interleaved in A1's messages regardless of when A1 or A3 sent their messages. (This is only true for FIFO and non-priority queues)